# how to reduce Oracle ADF Mobile Android Application size

Tags: mobile, size, oracle-adf, reduce

I have created one basic default application in ADF mobile 12c.its application size is 80 mb.which is horrible.It wont effect even after build it in release mode.It includes many libs and jars.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

With MAF 2.1 a simple android apk file is about 30mb when packaged in release mode.
That's because the container, which includes the JVM, has a fixed size.
If you are seeing 80mb, my guess is that you didn't actually packaged in release mode but rather in debug mode.